# Using erase-remove idiom on non-unique collections

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm, erase-remove-idiom

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    enum class En{A, B};
    std::vector<En> vec{En::A, En::B, En::A, En::B, En::A, En::B, En::A};
 
    for(const auto& i : vec) std::cout << int(i) << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    vec.erase(std::remove(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), vec.front()), 
              std::end(vec));

    for(const auto& i : vec) std::cout << int(i) << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Ideone**: http://ideone.com/NTPVyE

> **Prints:**
>
> 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
>
> 1, 0, 0, 0,

Why is this happening? Shouldn't only the first element of the vector be removed?

I suppose `std::remove` doesn't stop at the first element, but runs through the whole vector. Is there any way I can use the *erase-remove idiom* on collections with non-unique elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The third argument to `std::remove` is a `const` reference. You are changing the value of the element refered to as you move elements around, leading to undefined behaviour.

This would be well behaved:

```
auto elem = vec.front(); // copy front element
vec.erase(std::remove(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), elem), 
          std::end(vec));
```

Output:

> 1, 1, 1,

Comment: http://ideone.com/NTPVyE - This prints `1, 1, 1,` after the *erase-remove*. This is because `std::remove` shifts all elements that are equal to `En::A`. Is there a way to only affect "that specific `En::A`"? It's the reason I was using `vec.front()`. (In this simple example, what I want to achieve is the same behavior as `pop_front()`).

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: If you just want to erase that element, you don't need an algorithm, you just need `vec.erase(vec.begin());`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I feel dumb now. Thanks.